# Изменялся ли элемент формы Select?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо на форме проверить изменял ли пользователь элемент формы типа Select.

Как это сделать?

p.s.
пробовал так

```html
<select NAME="TEXT_FREQUENCY_TYPE_${row.ID}">
                            <option SELECTED VALUE="${row.FREQUENCY_TYPE}">${row.FREQUENCY_TYPE}</option>
                        </select>
```

```js
<script>
    function GetValue () {
        var result = [];

        [].forEach.call(document.querySelector('form').elements, function (el) {

            if (['checkbox', 'radio', 'button', 'submit'].indexOf(el.type) === -1 || el.checked)

            {
                var defValue = el.defaultValue;
                var currvalue = el.value;
                if (defValue == currvalue) {
                    result.push(el.name + ' :: ' + el.value+' :: '+" Значение не изменилось");
                } else {
                    result.push(el.name + ' :: ' + el.value+' :: '+" Значение изменилось с " + defValue +
                              "\n  на " + currvalue);
                }
</script>
```

результат:

```
TEXT_FREQUENCY_TYPE_1 :: Минут :: Значение изменилось с undefined на Минут
```

Comment: А для чего так делать?

Comment: el.defaultValue не существует, откуда вы его взяли?

Comment: Узнать менял ли пользователь значение элемента формы select на что-то другое отличное от первоначального значения, для дальнейшей обработки результата в сервлете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `SELECT` существует событие `change` - возникает при изменении значения.

```js
// Перебираем все формы
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form')).forEach(form => {
  // Перебираем все SELECT
  Array.from(form.querySelectorAll('select')).forEach(select => {
    // И вешаем на каждый SELECT обработчик события change
    select.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
  });
});

function changeHandler(){
  // Ищем родительскую форму, в ней DIV и помещаем в него сообщение
  this.closest('form').querySelector('div').innerHTML = 'SELECT в этой форме изменён!';
}
```

```css
form div{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type='text' />
  <select>
    <option value='one'>1</option>
    <option value='two'>2</option>
  </select>
  <div></div>
</form>
<hr />
<form>
  <input type='text' />
  <select>
    <option value='one'>1</option>
    <option value='two'>2</option>
  </select>
  <div></div>
</form>
<hr />
<form>
  <input type='text' />
  <select>
    <option value='one'>1</option>
    <option value='two'>2</option>
  </select>
  <div></div>
</form>
```